# Aws unlogged table restore

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have one postgres database instance on AWS, replica is allowed on that db instance, one table has been set as unlogged, in that case that table data is not getting replicated.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide more information? For example, what RDS database are you using? What do you mean by "unlogged"? Is it a [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) database?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [PostgreSQL: Documentation: 11: CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):

> **UNLOGGED**
>
> If specified, the table is created as an unlogged table. Data written to unlogged tables is not written to the write-ahead log (see Chapter 30), which makes them considerably faster than ordinary tables. However, they are not crash-safe: an unlogged table is automatically truncated after a crash or unclean shutdown. **The contents of an unlogged table are also not replicated to standby servers.** Any indexes created on an unlogged table are automatically unlogged as well.

Therefore, the behavior matches the documentation.

If you wish the table to be replicated, do not use an `UNLOGGED` table.